# angular: Jumping scrollbar in scroll panel of editText

Tags: css, angular5, scrollbar

My app has collapsible panel. It contains scroll panel with EditText (is generated by *ngFor). I was trying selve this by adding:

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll; /*not working*/
}
```

and another sollutions which i found in this [article](https://aykevl.nl/2014/09/fix-jumping-scrollbar), but it is not working.
Im also using *AutosizeModule* to resize EditText (ngx-autosize).

This problem looks like that:

[image]

Component:

```
    @Component({/* typical content */})
export class AnswerDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  answerText: string[] = [/*string values */'];

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  trackByIndex(index: number): any {
    return index;
  }
}
```

MyHtml:

```
<div id="answerDialog">
  <h3>Answers:</h3>
  <hr>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let i of answerText; let index =index; trackBy: trackByIndex;">
        <textarea autosize name="Text" class="input" [(ngModel)]="answerText[index]" ></textarea>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

my CSS:

```
#answerDialog {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -50px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #8BC3A3;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  background: #fefefe;
  max-height: 595px;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  right: 510px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-right: 0;
}

hr {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.input {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  color: #727272;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.input:hover {
  border: 1px solid #8BC3A3;
}

.input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #8BC3A3;
}

nav ul {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 505px;
  height: auto;
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll; /*not working*/
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #8BC3A3;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

Comment: hey, did you find a solution? If not can you create a plunkr or something?

I am not 100% sure but it looks like something that was recently fixed in ngx-autosize, please check the latest version

Comment: @chrystian I removed ngx-autosize and did scaling on my own :)

Comment: so it was actually ngx-autosize that was causing the trouble? can i ask you to test the latest version and write here if its any better?

Comment: @chrystian It works properly now